# How to dispatch action in a separate, parent component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am trying to work on an application that was built using react, redux, and react-router-redux.  It was built such that the header and footer-- react components-- are 'external' to the actual pages defined in the routes.  For example this is how `<App/>` looks like:

```
<Provider store={store}>
   <ConnectedRouter history={history}>           
      <div>
         <header/>
         {routes_for_pages}
         <footer/>
      </div>               
   </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

On one of the routes, their is a component that dispatches an action and, depending on the result returned, will need to update both header and footer with appropriate content.

How do I have the dispatch in that particular component also dispatch an action to both header and footer?  Problem I see is that the components (page components, header component, and footer component) don't know each other and they're composed as siblings.

Any help appreciated.  TIA.

Comment: You don't need to dispatch the action from multiple places, you can just catch the same action in multiple reducers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to dispatch the action from multiple components.
Instead, you should have multiple reducers that each do a different thing based on the dispatched action.

If you were using `redux-saga`, the code for this can be even cleaner.
You catch the initial action in a saga, and have the saga further dispatch a group of actions that should happen successively or together.

E.g.:

```
// saga handler
function* mySaga(action) {
  yield put('DO_SOMETHING');  // dispatches DO_SOMETHING
  yield put('UPDATE_HEADER'); // ...
  yield put('UPDATE_FOOTER'); // ...
}

function mySagaWatcher(
  takeLatest,
  'SOMETHING_TRIGGERED_THIS_ACTION',
  mySaga
);
```